# Handling empty json in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json, api

When retrieving the data from the backend via API, I want to check if a domain is valid or not. The issue is that when it is not valid (i.e. the domain does not exist in the backend, I receive an empty array [])

I have then used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` in the frontend to get my data. I know that I could have used the response directly as it was, as I am sending it as JSON, but I wanted to test some things.

Please see the API below in the backend:

```
import Domains from "../models/DomainsModel.js";

export const Whois = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { domain } = req.body;

    const domainz = await Domains.findAll({
      where: {
        domain: domain,
      },
      attributes: {
        exclude: ["id", "userEmail", "arecord", "updatedAt"],
      },
      raw: true,
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result) {
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Implementation of the function in front end :

```
const whoisForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/whois", {
        domain: domain,
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        try {
          const datar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp));

          Moment.locale("en");

          let DomainWhois = datar.data[0].domain;
          let DomainCreatedAt = Moment(datar.data[0].createdAt).format(
            "DD MMM YYYY"
          );

          setDomainWhois(DomainWhois);
          setDomainCreatedAt(DomainCreatedAt);

          let eroareDomain =
            DomainWhois +
            " is already taken and was registered on: " +
            DomainCreatedAt;
          let successDomain =
            DomainWhois +
            " is available for purchase, you can register it now!";

          if (isEmptyObject(datar.data)) {
            setSuccessMesaj(successDomain);
          } else {
            setEroareMesaj(eroareDomain);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("err: " + err);
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error" + error);
  }
};
```

I have tried the IF..ELSE with various functions, including:

1. datar.data.length === 0
2. !Array.isArray(datar.data) || !datar.data.length

I get the following error when response from API is empty []:

```
err: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domain')
```

What to do next?

**UPDATE 1**
The response for a successful response (i.e. data exists in the database) is:

```
[{"domain":"test.com","createdAt":"2022-09-20T13:33:08.000Z"}]
```

The response for an unsuccessful response (i.e. no data in the database) is:

```
[]
```

I want, when it is blank, to show a message that the domain you are trying to register is available.

**Update 2**

Response of JSON with data and without data
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can add your API response also for reference.

Comment: Hello @SatejBidvai , I have provided the API response to the main question. Thanks :)

Comment: [][0].domain doesn't exist in [] so if ([].length > 1) { ... } run your logic maybe try or even if (datar[0].hasOwnProperty('domain') === true) { ... }

Comment: Hello @CotyEmbry , I have tried both and they are not working, the reason would be that when doing a console.log ( datar.data[0].hasOwnProperty('domain') ), returns true if it has data, if not it will not return anything, I would expect false, but ...

Comment: Assuming the array you provided is the `response.data`:
When  response from API is empty, your data[0] does not exists, so data[0].domain is giving you an error as data[0] itself does not exists.

Comment: what does `console.log(resp)` look like with empty data, is it null or is it `[]` or is it `""` etc?

Comment: Hi @CotyEmbry it is `[]` , I have updated the main question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear where you tried to check the conditions, but you're probably not preventing access to the undefined variable. I rewrote your code to take that into consideration

```
const whoisForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/whois", {
        domain: domain,
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        try {
          Moment.locale("en");

          if (resp.data.length > 0) {
            let DomainWhois = resp.data[0].domain;
            let DomainCreatedAt = Moment(datar.data[0].createdAt).format(
              "DD MMM YYYY"
            );
            setDomainWhois(DomainWhois);
            setDomainCreatedAt(DomainCreatedAt);
            let eroareDomain =
              DomainWhois +
              " is already taken and was registered on: " +
              DomainCreatedAt;
            setEroareMesaj(eroareDomain);
          } else {
            let successDomain =
              DomainWhois +
              " is available for purchase, you can register it now!";
            setSuccessMesaj(successDomain);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("err: " + err);
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error" + error);
  }
};
```

I don't think you need to parse and then stringify the resp since it's already an object.

Comment: Thank you @diedu , it works, I am reading the implementation to see exactly the lack of code from my side